# when Export to pdf from SAP font Size decreased

Tags: crystal-reports, report, font-size, export-to-pdf, sap-business-one-di-api

My problem is very simple, I designed a crystal report (2013) and then put it on SAP business one, but when I extract report as pdf from SAP, the font size decreases from as usual,

I tried the changes in registry key, i.e. **HKey_Local_Machine, ** but it still did not work, Here I mentioned the Changes, I tried Adjustment value from 2 - 9, but all in vain,
what is the solution? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs2ln.png)